# useState create infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, next.js, use-state

I am creating a web application with next and tailwind, I need to pass a series of data between methods for which I am using a useState, but when loading it keeps loading with ridiculous RAM usage and never charges.

Component:

```
export default function Home({ nav, footer, content, edition }) {

const [activeEdition, setActiveEdition] = useState({
 background: '',
 title: '',
 prize: '',
 sponsors: [], 
});

return (
 <div>
  
  {edition.map((result) => {
    
    const { data } = result;  

    if(data.active){
      setActiveEdition({
        background: data.edition_background.url,
        title: data.edition_title,
        prize: data.prize.url,
        sopnsors: data.body[0].items,
      });
    }

    return (
      null
    )
  })}

  {content.map((result) => {
    const active = activeEdition
    const { data } = result

    return (
      <Hero
        key = {data.id}
        active = {active}

      />
    )
  })}
  
</div>
 );
}
```

Implementation:

```
function Hero({heroData, active, register}) {
    const background = {
        backgroundImage: `url('${active}')`
    }
    
    console.log(active)

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>asdas</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Hero
```

Update: complete compnent added for a better understanding

Comment: It looks like you're setting the state inside the `render` logic. That would cause the state to update and the component to rerender. And with every rerender the state is set again and the loop continues. Could you add more of the component that causes the infinite loop?

Comment: Sure I'll update de question

Comment: I see you set state in the map loop which probably is done in rendering. You should use useEffect for changing state and not trigger changes in the rendering process.

Comment: @M.Argumedo I think he means the `{edition.map(...)}` looks like it's embedded in some JSX or something, it's not in a file by itself right? Can you show us the rest of that file?

Comment: What is the intent behind calling `setActiveEdition()` inside the JSX? JSX code is for displaying stuff, not changing stuff.

Comment: I've update the code, I can't put the entire file but edition comes from an API

Comment: OGordo answered below. You should accept as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the map into useEffect hook, also no need for map since you don't transform data, just iterate and make a change based on the value. Also added a break since I assume only one item will match the criteria.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  for (const result of edition) {

    const { data } = result;  

    if(data.active){
      setActiveEdition({
        background: data.edition_background.url,
        title: data.edition_title,
        prize: data.prize.url,
        sopnsors: data.body[0].items,
      });
      break;
    }

  }}, [edition]);
```

Like I mentioned in the comment: you are creating an infinite loop because you modify state upon render. What you want is to update state based on edition changes. This side effect is supposed to be done in useEffect.